# Trimming blank spaces in Excel without losing formatting

Tags: excel, vba

I've located an Excel macro that will trim trailing spaces:

```
Sub trimspace()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(2, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then
        'optimize performance
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        'trim cells incl char 160
        For Each c In rngConstants
            c.Value = Trim$(Application.Clean(Replace(c.Value, Chr(160), " ")))
        Next c
        'reset settings
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

The problem is that when run on a cell that contains partial formatting, the formatting is lost. For example, "This **here** is formatted.  " becomes "This here is formatted."

I've modified the code to iterate through the string and only retain the left portion, but the left() function also deletes the formatting.

```
Sub trimspace2()
    Dim c As Range
    Dim rngConstants As Range
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rngConstants = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.SpecialCells(2, 2)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not rngConstants Is Nothing Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        For Each c In rngConstants
            While Asc(Right(c.Value, 1)) = 32
                c.Value = Left(c.Value, Len(c.Value) - 1)
            Wend
        Next c
        Application.ScreenUpdating = True
        Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    End If
End Sub
```

Is there a manual method for deleting the last character during iteration to avoid processing the formatted portion of the cell value? Or a workaround to keep formatting with trim()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to preserve any formatting which has been applied to only part of a cell's content, you must use the cell's `Characters` property to modify the content.

For example to remove the last character:

```
c.Characters(Len(c.Value),1).Delete
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.characters